# Connected component of an open set is itself open and connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

This is from Stein's complex analysis text (Exercise 1.6):

> Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and $z \in \Omega$. Let $\mathscr{C}_z$ be the connected component of $z$ in $\Omega$ (the set of all points $w$ in $\Omega$ that can be joined to $z$ by a curve entirely contained in $\Omega$). Show that $\mathscr{C}_z$ is open and connected.

So far I have that the connected part is true by definition. I am a bit less certain on showing openness. Since $\Omega$ is open, for all $x \in \mathscr{C}_z$, $\exists ~\epsilon > 0$ s.t. $B_\epsilon(x) \subset \Omega$. However, I am struggling to show that $B_\epsilon(x) \subset \mathscr{C}_z$ to finish the proof.

Comment: If you take any point $y \in B_\epsilon(x)$, can you find a curve from $y$ to $x$? If yes, you can concatenate this curve with the one from $x$ to $z$ (which exists by definition) to obtain a curve from $y$ to $z$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathcal C_z$ and $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ are connected and they have a point in common. This implies that their union is connceted. By definition of connected component this implies that $\mathcal C_z \cup B_{\epsilon}(x)=\mathcal C_z$. This implies that $B_\epsilon(x) \subset \mathscr{C}_z$

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck on trying to show that $B_\epsilon(x)$ is connected but reading your answer made me realize that's trivially true. Thanks!